# What is the difference between inboard and outboard engines on a Russian IL-18 turboprop?

Tags: aircraft-design

I was looking at this picture of an Ilyushin IL-18 turboprop aircraft
[image: IL-18 view]
<sup>Image hosted at https://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/160630220221-north-korea-air-koryo-il-18-nose-super-169.jpg</sup>
 and noticed that the outboard engines look significantly smaller than the inboard engines. Wikipedia lists [specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-18#Specifications_.28Il-18D.29) for four identical engines but the outboard cowlings don't seem to have air intakes.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Great question, Howard! You've got the link to your image, can you post the link that lead you there, for attribution purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inboard cowlings seem to follow a different design structure in order to make room for the landing gear compartment. The air intakes are moved aft on the outboard cowlings.

Comment: I see that now. Good answer!